# Solving for calibration quaternion

Tags: android, rotation, quaternions

I'm writing an Android app that requires the rotation vector. I'd like to use the `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` but in some of my test devices the magnetometer doesn't perform well to say the least. Instead, the `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` provides much smoother data (but I can't get direction relative to the Earth). What I ended up doing is while my data is loading, I run both virtual sensors. I now have an average quaternion for both, call them *R* (`TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`) and *R<sub>g</sub>* (`TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR`).

Once calibration is over I only run the `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR`, but would like to correct it for North. What I **think** I can do is something like: `R = Rg * C` where *C* is my calibration and *R<sub>g</sub>* is the new `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` data after a low pass filter. What I tried:

```
1. R = Rg * C
2. R * R' = Rg * C * R'
3. U = Rg * C * R' // Here U is the unit quaternion
4. C * R' = Rg'    // This is because quaternion multiplication is associative
                   // Rg * (C * R') = U from line 3 therefore (C * R') must be
                   // equal to the conjugate of Rg
5. C = Rg' * R''   // I found this online somewhere (I hope this is right)
6. C = Rg' * R     // R'' is just R
```

Now that I have `C`, I can take new values (after low pass filter) for the `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` multiply them by `C` and get the actual rotation quaternion `R` that should be similar to the one that would have been provided by the `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` with a steady North.

This gets me pretty close, but it doesn't quite work. I'm testing using a very simple AR like app that shows an item (who's position is determined by the device orientation) floating on the screen. If I leave out the calibration the character shows up and tracks perfectly, but it doesn't show up North of me (I have it fixed at (0, 1, 0) for now). If I take the rotation vector, get the quaternion, multiply by the calibration constant, the tracking gets thrown off:

1. Rotating the device about the Y axis shifts the item correctly horizontally, but it also adds a vertical component where rotating in the positive direction (using right hand rule) moves my item up (negative Y on the screen).
2. Rotating the device about the X axis shifts the item correctly vertically, but it also adds a horizontal component where rotation in the positive direction (using right hand rule) moves my item right (positive X on the screen).
3. Rotating the device about the Z axis works.

Sorry for the long description, I just want to make sure all the details are there. Summary of the question: I want to be able to get a rotation matrix that is roughly north and avoid using the magnetometer. I'm trying to do this by taking the average difference between `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` and `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` and using that to "calibrate" future values from the `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` but it doesn't work. Does anyone know what the issue might be with how I'm calculating the calibration (or any other part of this)?

Some additional info:

```
private float[] values = null
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    values = lowPass(event.values.clone(), values);
    Quaternion rawQuaternion = Quaternion.fromRotationVector(values);
    Quaternion calibratedQuaternion = rawQuaternion.mult(calibration);
    float[] rotationMatrix = calibratedQuaternion.getRotationMatrix();

    float[] pos = new float[] { 0f, 1f, 0f, 1f };
    Matrix.multiplyMV(pos, 0, rotationMatrix, 0, pos, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(pos, 0, matrixMVP, 0, pos, 0);
    // Screen position should be found at pos[0], -pos[1] on a [-1,1] scale
}

Quaternion fromRotationVector(float[] r) {
    float[] Q = new float[4];
    SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(Q, r);
    return new Quaternion(Q);
}

Quaternion mult(Quaternion q) {
    Quaternion qu = new Quaternion();
    qu.w = w*q.w - x*q.x - y*q.y - z*q.z;
    qu.x = w*q.x + x*q.w + y*q.z - z*q.y;
    qu.y = w*q.y + y*q.w + z*q.x - x*q.z;
    qu.z = w*q.z + z*q.w + x*q.y - y*q.x;
    return qu;
}

float[] getRotationMatrix() {
    float[] M = new float[16];
    float[] V = new float[] { x, y, z, w };
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(M, V);
    return M;
}
```

Comment: Could you solve your issue? I also have a similar problem where I cannot seem to make the static calibration apply properly to all quaternion values. If you resolved your issue, any pointers would help. I'm searching and will post an answer once I find out the right solution.

Comment: I can't say I really resolved the issue... I got around it and things kinda work. I'm in the middle of something but I'll post some code (my company agreed to release this as a free library when we have a few spare cycles so the full code should be available on github soonish).

Comment: I'm glad you found a way to go around it. Looking forward to the code. Hopefully, it'll fix my issue too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and did some research and realized where the problem is. So basically, by only looking at a stationary orientation of the IMU, you only align one axis of the coordinate system which is the vertical axis in the direction of gravity. That's why you rotations around Z axis works fine.

To complete your static calibrations, you have to include a planar motion and find the principal vectors of the motion which will be the, say, your X axis. Y axis follows the right-hand rule.

Simply, rotate the IMU around the global X axis and look at the gyroscope outputs of your IMU. The principal component of your gyroscope should be towards the X axis. After finding the Z axis in the first step and X axis in the second step, you can find Y axis by the cross product of the two. Using these axes, create the rotation matrix or the quaternion for the translations.

Comment: It sounds like in your case the biggest issue is that the axes weren't aligned as you expected. In my case I found that the compass drifts, which means that if I use the ROTATION_VECTOR for an AR application, my objects drift. So I want to calibrate my GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR to roughly point North. See my answer below for how I'm doing it right now.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get a sense of where North is without reliable magnetometer data. You mentioned that your workaround did the trick for you; but have you tried using any complementary filter to get rid of you compass drift?

Comment: The `ROTATION_VECTOR` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate) gives us the rotation in 3D needed to align the device to magnetic N. The issue is that some devices have a crummy magnetometer so N drifts and so this sensor is not suitable for AR. the `GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-gamerot) is the same but uses an arbitrary N. What my code does is runs both and computes the average diff, uses that as an offset to the game sensor which drifts less.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing (there are some changes coming soon and once done I'll publish it on jcenter as a library). What this tries to solve is being able to run the Game Rotation Vector sensor (which has much less drift than the Rotation Vector sensor) while still pointing roughly north. Answer is in Kotlin:

```
class RotationMatrixLiveData(context Context): LiveData<FloatArray>(), SensorEventListener {
    private val sensorManager = context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    private val rotationSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)
    private val gameRotationSensor =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR)
        else null

    private var isActive = false
    private var isCalibrating = false
    private var rotationValues: FloatArray? = null

    var calibrationCount = 0
    var calibrationQuaternion: FloatArray? = null
    var calibrationGameCount = 0
    var calibrationGameQuat: FloatArray? = null
    var calibration: Quaternion? = null
    var rotationQuaternionValues = FloatArray(4)
    var gameQuaternionValues = FloatArray(4)

private val rotationVectorQuaternion = Quaternion()

    init {
        value = floatArrayOf(
                1f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                0f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
                0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
    }

    /**
     * Starts calibrating the rotation matrix (if the game rotation vector sensor
     * is available.
     */
    fun beginCalibration() {
        gameRotationSensor?.let {
            isCalibrating = true
            calibration = null
            calibrationQuaternion = null
            calibrationCount = 0
            calibrationGameQuat = null
            calibrationGameCount = 0
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, rotationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, it, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop calibrating the rotation matrix.
     */
    fun stopCalibration() {
        isCalibrating = false
        if (!isActive) {
            // Not active, just turn off everthing
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
        } else if (gameRotationSensor != null) {
            // Active and has both sensors, turn off rotation and leave the game rotation running
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, rotationSensor)
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        isActive = true
        val sensor = gameRotationSensor ?: rotationSensor
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        isActive = false
        if (!isCalibrating) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
        }
    }

    //
    // SensorEventListener
    //

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {}

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
        if (isCalibrating) {
            if (event.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
                SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(rotationQuaternionValues, event.values)
                calibrationQuaternion?.let { quat ->
                    for (i in 0..3) {
                        rotationQuaternionValues[i] += quat[i]
                    }
                }
                calibrationQuaternion = rotationQuaternionValues
                calibrationCount++
            } else if (event.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
                SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(gameQuaternionValues, event.values)
                calibrationGameQuat?.let {quat ->
                    for (i in 0..3) {
                        gameQuaternionValues[i] += quat[i]
                    }
                }
                calibrationGameQuat = gameQuaternionValues
                calibrationGameCount++
            }
        } else if (gameRotationSensor == null || event.sensor.type != Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            // Only calculate rotation if there is no game rotation sensor or if the event is a game
            // rotation

            val calibrationQ = calibrationQuaternion
            val calibrationQg = calibrationGameQuat
            if (calibrationQ != null && calibrationQg != null) {
                for (i in 0..3) {
                    calibrationQ[i] /= calibrationCount.toFloat()
                    calibrationQg[i] /= calibrationGameCount.toFloat()
                }
                calibration = (Quaternion(calibrationQg).apply { conjugate() } *
                        Quaternion(calibrationQ)).apply {
                    x = 0f
                    y = 0f
                    normalize()
                }
            }
            calibrationQuaternion = null
            calibrationGameQuat = null

            // Run values through low-pass filter
            val values = lowPass(event.values, rotationValues)
            rotationValues = values

            rotationVectorQuaternion.setFromRotationVector(values)

            // Calibrate if available
            calibration?.let { rotationVectorQuaternion.preMult(it) }

            // Generate rotation matrix
            value = rotationVectorQuaternion.getRotationMatrix(value)
        }
    }
}
```

For the quaternion class I'm using:

```
class Quaternion(val values: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(1f, 0f, 0f, 0f)) {

    companion object {
        fun fromRotationVector(rv: FloatArray): Quaternion {
            val Q = FloatArray(4)
            SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(Q, rv)
            return Quaternion(Q)
        }
    }

    private val buffer = FloatArray(4)

    var w: Float
        get() = values[0]
        set(value) { values[0] = value }
    var x: Float
        get() = values[1]
        set(value) { values[1] = value }
    var y: Float
        get() = values[2]
        set(value) { values[2] = value }
    var z: Float
        get() = values[3]
        set(value) { values[3] = value }

    fun setFromRotationVector(rv: FloatArray) {
        SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(values, rv)
    }

    fun conjugate() {
        x = -x
        y = -y
        z = -z
    }

    fun getRotationMatrix(R: FloatArray? = null): FloatArray {
        val matrix = R ?: FloatArray(16)
        for (i in 0..3) {
            buffer[i] = values[(i+1)%4]
        }
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(matrix, buffer)
        return matrix
    }

    fun magnitude(): Float {
        var mag = 0f
        for (i in 0..3) {
            mag += values[i]*values[i]
        }
        return Math.sqrt(mag.toDouble()).toFloat()
    }

    fun normalize() {
        val mag = magnitude()
        x /= mag
        y /= mag
        z /= mag
        w /= mag
    }

    fun preMult(left: Quaternion) {
        buffer[0] = left.w*this.w - left.x*this.x - left.y*this.y - left.z*this.z
        buffer[1] = left.w*this.x + left.x*this.w + left.y*this.z - left.z*this.y
        buffer[2] = left.w*this.y + left.y*this.w + left.z*this.x - left.x*this.z
        buffer[3] = left.w*this.z + left.z*this.w + left.x*this.y - left.y*this.x

        for (i in 0..3) {
            values[i] = buffer[i]
        }
    }

    operator fun times(q: Quaternion): Quaternion {
        val qu = Quaternion()
        qu.w = w*q.w - x*q.x - y*q.y - z*q.z
        qu.x = w*q.x + x*q.w + y*q.z - z*q.y
        qu.y = w*q.y + y*q.w + z*q.x - x*q.z
        qu.z = w*q.z + z*q.w + x*q.y - y*q.x
        return qu
    }

    operator fun times(v: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        val conj = Quaternion(values.clone()).apply { conjugate() }
        return multiplyQV(multiplyQV(values, v), conj.values)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "(${w.toString(5)}(w), ${x.toString(5)}, ${y.toString(5)}, ${z.toString(5)}) |${magnitude().toString(5)}|"
    }

    private fun multiplyQV(q: FloatArray, r: FloatArray): FloatArray {
        val result = FloatArray(4)
        result[0] = r[0]*q[0]-r[1]*q[1]-r[2]*q[2]-r[3]*q[3]
        result[1] = r[0]*q[1]+r[1]*q[0]-r[2]*q[3]+r[3]*q[2]
        result[2] = r[0]*q[2]+r[1]*q[3]+r[2]*q[0]-r[3]*q[1]
        result[3] = r[0]*q[3]-r[1]*q[2]+r[2]*q[1]+r[3]*q[0]
        return result
    }
}
```